# How to avoid using "using System.Web.Optimization" in layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I started empty project so there was no `@Styles.Render`, I had to download **Web.Optimization** from nuget packages and create **BundleConfig.cs** class in **App_Start** folder. Then do avoid writing `@using System.Web.Optimization` in my **_Layout.cshtml** I added namespace in the Web.config in the **Views** folder.

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
        ...
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        ...
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

But this not solved my problem, I still need to write `@using System.Web.Optimization`. What I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you _need_ to write the using statement? What happens if you don't? When do you get an error if any, design time, runtime or both? Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you cleaned your solution and then rebuilt it? It seems like you should have access once you include this directive.

Comment: It was giving `The name Styles does not exist in the current context` even after rebuilding. But after restarting the program it worked :) Thank you guys

Comment: @xoemab - I would recommend adding your comment as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

As you described, the only way is to add the namespace in the following part of your web.config in the views folder (or the appropriate parent folder if your views are in a different area) :

```
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
     <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        ...
     </namespaces>
  </pages>
```

just add the following line :

```
  <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
```

You will need to **rebuild the solution** to make it effective.

Depending on the version of ASP.NET and Visual Studio (there are some incompatibilities between versions), you may need to also:

- close and reopen your layout file (.cshtml).
- restart Visual Studio if the previous item didn't work.

Comment: Don't forget to close and reopen the layout.  After adding the namespace to the web.config, and removing "@using", I cleaned and rebuilt the solution, but still saw the error until I thought to reopen it. ;)

Comment: @JamesWilkins : you mean closing and reopening the cshtml was enough? I was a bit drastic and reopened VS instead. If you confirm reopening the cshtml was enough, I'll add it in the answer.

Comment: All I can say is that's what I did, and it worked.  I never closed VS at all.  In fact, I just continued on to coding. ;) Perhaps say to reopen the file, and restart VS only if that fails.  One setup can be quirky compared to others; wouldn't surprise me. ;)

Comment: @JamesWilkins : Done, thanks for giving me an opportunity to improve my answer :)